# Is there a such thing as "starvation mode"?

Tags: nutrition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [6-meals-a-day strategy](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/325/6-meals-a-day-strategy)

Often I hear claims that not eating enough calories will put your body in "starvation mode" and actually make you gain weight. Simply from an energy perspective, this seems impossible and there is a ton of anecdotal evidence to suggest otherwise. Is there any actual proof of such a claim?

Comment: This "dupe" doesn't really answer the question, it more approaches it from the other side of eating very often versus a standard 3 meals a day...

Comment: Answers to this question would be perfectly appropriate in the dupe, which explicitly asks about starvation mode.

Comment: I don't see any answers in the other question that confirm or deny the existence of 'starvation mode'. Also, any answer here has nothing to do with the 6-meal-a-day-strategy question, which simply asked whether the diet was effective, regardless of the mechanism - be it preventing the body from entering 'starvation mode' or be it something else.

Comment: I don't think the claim is that "starvation mode" makes you _gain_ weight, but that it causes you to burn calories (and thus lose weight) more slowly.  Therefore, when you do eat again, you may gain weight, or at minimum continue to burn weight at a slower rate than you would have if you had never entered "starvation mode." Although since you haven't provided a source for your claim, it's hard to be sure we're talking about the same phenomenon.

Comment: @alain you are correct, but the other question can be answered instead of this. Since "starvation mode" is not so hot on the site, it makes sense not to dilute effort over two questions.